# React-Navigation and TypeScript. Property 'getScreen' is missing in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-navigation

Using TypeScript and react-navigation is get the following TypeScript issue:

```
  Property 'Principles' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ screen: (props: any) => Element; path: string; }' is not assignable to type 'NavigationRouteConfig'.
      Type '{ screen: (props: any) => Element; path: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ navigationOptions?: any; path?: string; } & { getScreen: () => NavigationComponent; }'.
        Type '{ screen: (props: any) => Element; path: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ getScreen: () => NavigationComponent; }'.
          Property 'getScreen' is missing in type '{ screen: (props: any) => Element; path: string; }'.
```

Here is the code in my  navigator:

```
const MainNavigator: NavigationContainer = StackNavigator({
    Principles: {
      screen: props => <WebViewModal source={{ uri: MY_URI }} {...props} />,
      path: 'principles',
    },
})
```

And that is the code of the `WebViewModal`:

```
export interface IWebViewModalProps extends WebViewProperties, NavigationScreenProps {}

class WebViewModal extends Component<IWebViewModalProps> {
  closeModal = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  };

  render() {
    const {...props } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TopNavigationBar left={<Icon name="close" onPress={this.closeModal} />} />
        <WebView {...props} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default WebViewModal;
```

How can I fix this typescript issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the index.d.ts of react-navigation, I see that you can do something like:

```
Principles: {
  getScreen: () => props => <WebViewModal source={{ uri: MY_URI }} {...props} />,
  path: 'principles',
},
```

However, I was also able to get rid of this error when I saw it without changing the code, but simply deleted node_modules and yarn.lock and ran *yarn install* again.

Comment: I see the same thing. Really strange.